# Javascript onunload

Tags: javascript, exit, onunload

I have most of this script written but I know I am missing one key pice.

I need to call function (see below)...

```
function InternalLink() {
Page_ShowPopOnExit = false;
}
```

...in an if/else statement somehow inside (see code below) to detect that what has been clicked was an internal link and not a page close/external link.

```
    function LinkConvert() {
var href;
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

                for(var y=0; y<anchors.length; y++)
                {
                                href = anchors[y].href.toLowerCase();
                                if (!(href.indexOf("http://")!=-1 && href.indexOf(MySiteDomain)==-1))
                                                {
                                                anchors[y].clickhandler=InternalLink()
                                                XBrowserAddHandlerPops(anchors[y],"click","clickhandler");
                                                }
                }
}
```

The (**latest**) total code is below, Ty for helping me finish my code (or fix it :)

```
function exitwindow() {
var Page_ShowPopOnExit=true;
var MySiteDomain='www.example.com';
var url = '/exit.html';
var win = 'toolbar=0,directories=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=250,height=300';
if (Page_ShowPopOnExit==true){
   open(url,'WindowName',win);
   } else (Page_ShowPopOnExit==false)
   {alert('Internal Link')}
}

function InternalLink() {
  Page_ShowPopOnExit = false;
}

function LinkConvert() {
var href;
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

                for(var y=0; y<anchors.length; y++)
                {
                                href = anchors[y].href.toLowerCase();
                                if (!(href.indexOf("http://")!=-1 && href.indexOf(MySiteDomain)==-1))
                                                {
                                                anchors[y].clickhandler=InternalLink()
                                                XBrowserAddHandlerPops(anchors[y],"click","clickhandler");
                                                }
                }
}
function XBrowserAddHandlerPops(target,eventName,handlerName) {
  if ( target.addEventListener ) {
    target.addEventListener(eventName, function(e){target[handlerName](e);}, false);
  } else if ( target.attachEvent ) {
    target.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(e){target[handlerName](e);});
  } else {
    var originalHandler = target["on" + eventName];
    if ( originalHandler ) {
      target["on" + eventName] = function(e){originalHandler(e);target[handlerName](e);};
    } else {
      target["on" + eventName] = target[handlerName];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your code you want to make a popup when a visitor clicks a link that links to different domain.

Your code currently does this by attaching an onclick handler to all links if the link URL looks like an internal link (there is no "http://" or the domain is present). It will then set a boolean `Page_ShowPopOnExit` to false which should prevent the popup hook from generating a popup when it is called (`exitwindow` - which isn't being called in your sample code)

I think there is a simpler way. Namely just attach an onclick handler that *will* make a popup to each link that isn't an internal link:

```
function createPopup() {
    var url = '/exitexample.html';
    var win ='toolbar=0,directories=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=250,height=300';
    open(url,'WindowName',win);
}

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var y=0; y<anchors.length; y++) {
    href = anchors[y].href.toLowerCase();
    if (href.indexOf("http://") !== -1 && href.indexOf(MySiteDomain) !==-1) {
        anchors[y].onclick = createPopup; // you might want to replace this with attachEventListener etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal of the code is to fire only when the window is closed or the user goes to say "google.com"

Comment: Then you could additionally attach an onunload event on the window which also calls `createPopup`. The links are already covered.

Comment: So you are recommending the following
`function createPopup() {
    var url = '/exitexample.html';
    var win ='toolbar=0,directories=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=250,height=300';
    open(url,'WindowName',win);
}
var MySiteDomain='www.example.com';
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var y=0; y<anchors.length; y++) {
    href = anchors[y].href.toLowerCase();
    if (href.indexOf("http://") !== -1 && href.indexOf(MySiteDomain) !==-1) {
        anchors[y].onunload = createPopup;
    }
}`

Comment: No. The `onunload` should be attached to the window, not to the anchors. Just add `window.onunload = createPopup;`

Comment: Ok close, but the function is still firing for internal links,

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
window.onunload = function() { 
  createPopup();
}
</script>`

external .js

`function createPopup() {
    var url = '/exitexample.html';
    var win ='toolbar=0,directories=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=250,height=300';
    open(url,'WindowName',win);
}
var MySiteDomain='www.exm.com';
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var y=0; y<anchors.length; y++) {
    href = anchors[y].href.toLowerCase();
    if (href.indexOf("http://") !== -1 && href.indexOf(MySiteDomain) !==-1) {
        anchors[y].onclick = createPopup;
    }
}`

Comment: I guess I am back to my org problem. Trying to stop the popup from firing when an internal link is clicked.

Comment: You do realize that you have to change the value of `MySiteDomain`, right?

Comment: internal links on the page are coded as `<a href="/example.aspx">example</a>`

Comment: anymore help would be appreciated. Im a little out of my depths right now.

Comment: make sure the condition in the `if` is correct, in that it will be `false` for internal links

Comment: Would it help if I put a test site. Im still new at this, some of the code I found online and trying to alter to the function I require.